# Find the local extemum of $x^{2}-2y^{2} - \ln (x + y)$

Tags: functions, derivatives, hessian-matrix

I have to find the local extrmum of the function $$f(x, y) = x^{2}-2y^{2} - \ln (x + y).$$
I found the first derivatives of $$f'_x = 2x-\frac{1}{x+y}$$ $$f'_y = -4y-\frac{1}{x+y}$$
I made the system $f'_x=0$ and  $f'_y = 0$. I found points $A (-1, \frac{1}{2})$ and $B (1, -\frac{1}{2}).$

After that, I found second derivatives $f''_x = 2 + \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}$, $f''_y = - 4 + \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}, $, $f''_{xy} = \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}$, $f''_{yx} = \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}$.
Then I made The Hessian matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
2 + \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}} & \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}\\ 
\frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}} & -4 + \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}
\end{bmatrix}$.

The Problem is that the determinant is $\frac{-8x^{4}-32x^{3}y-48x^{2}y^{2}-2x^2-32xy^3-4xy-8y^4-2y^2}{(x+y)^4}$.

How I can find the local extremum then?

Comment: In the Hessian matrix, you must replace $x$ and $y$ by their values at each critical point.

Comment: Also $f$ is only defined when $x+y$ is positive.

Comment: That means that i have to replace x y with A (-1, 1/2) and B(1, - 1/2). In that way, I'll have two Hessian matrix

Comment: Yes you normally have a different Hessian matrix at each point. In your case however, one of the points is invalid.

Comment: In your opinion, are my critical points correct?

Comment: One of them is correct, the other one is not.

Comment: but why you think like that?

Comment: Ask your calculator the value of $f$ at each point, and you'll see why I think this way.

Comment: If the Hessian is negative at the extreme point and the second derivative with respect to $x$ is negative, the only extreme point is a maximum point. This happens for the coordinate point $1,-1/2$.